# eth_sendTransaction gas required exceeds allowance

Tags: go-ethereum, php, sendtransaction

```
$result = $client->callMethod('eth_sendTransaction', [array(
                    "from" => $address->address,
                    "to" => "0xac52822dde76b9c4cd701d5f4402acedb2a86cc1",
                    "value" => "0x" . strval(dechex($amount)),
                    "gasPrice" => "0x" . strval(dechex($gasPrice))
                )]);
```

Hi, when I call the function above I get this result:

```
{ ["jsonrpc"]=> string(3) "2.0" ["id"]=> int(1) ["error"]=> array(2) { ["code"]=> int(-32000) ["message"]=> string(70) "gas required exceeds allowance (9958635) or always failing transaction" } }
```

Could you please help me what is wrong? I've tried to increase gasLimit, but got the same result. Also I'm running geth light node if it helps.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure on how it works with php but why are you adding "0x" to the `value` and `gasPrice`? In javascript with web3.js you just assign those fields as integers not hexvalues

Comment: It's because default php convert function to hexadecimal convert number without 0x so I'm adding it later

Comment: This sounds like the `from` account doesn't have enough balance. How much does it have and is it less than the gasLimit multiplied by the gasPrice?

Comment: Balance is 0.05 and I'm sending 0.02 so balance should be ok